# monorepo typeScript config typeRoots not work

Tags: typescript, monorepo

create a types file index.d.ts in root, in workspaces app tsconfig.json option typeRoots;['../../types/index.d.ts'], but declare until prompt can't not found

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/zen-snow-t4jwvt?file=%2Fsample%2Fmain%2Ftsconfig.json%3A5%2C6-5%2C15)

move types file to workspaces app can work good

all app in workspaces can import a common types index.d.ts file